# How to make field to filter optional in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, filter

I have to get some data from order collection and I wrote this piece of code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $incrementId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

The problem is that I want to make a field `"increment_id"` a optional one. If variable `$incrementId` will be a null the code:

```
-addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $incrementId)
```

should be not considered.

Answer (score 2):

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
if (!is_null($incrementId)) {
    $order->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $incrementId);
}
```

Comment: the simplest solutions are the best :)